# Getting repository object null in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have below project structure

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYXND.png]

My code files are as belows

**DemoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        CarListGrabber grabber = new CarListGrabber();
        grabber.grabCarsWithName("Test");
    }

}
```

**NewCarRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface NewCarRepository extends CrudRepository<NewCar, Long> {

}
```

**NewCar.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "new_car_details")
public class NewCar {
    // member variables with default constructor
}
```

**CarListGrabber.java**

```
@Service
public class CarListGrabber {

    @Autowired
    private NewCarRepository newCarRepository;

    // someOtherStuff
}
```

Even though I have used annotations  @Repository, @Service I am getting null repository object in service.

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating a new `CarListGrabber` with:

```
CarListGrabber grabber = new CarListGrabber();
```

it will not make injections you need to inject also your `grabber`, like:

```
@Autowired
CarListGrabber grabber;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Thank you very much. I really appreciate for your help.